# python : why use %s instead of calling variables directly

Tags: python

I was just wondering why use %s instead of calling the variable directly ex:

```
playername = "george" 

print "my name is %s" % playername
print "my name is", playername
```

calling the variable directly is a little shorter and they both print the same results so is there something i have not learned about yet that will come back to bite me if i forgo the use of the %?

Comment: Consider this, what if you had more than one variable to inject into the string? How would that string look like? What's more readable?

Comment: If you ever translate into another language you will be thankful that you use format strings.

Comment: Also, if you don't want a space then you will need string formatting.

Comment: such as:                                                    playername = "george" 

print "my name is %s" % playername
print "my name is", playername

Comment: nevermind that last comment it wont let me format it right but i see what you mean when more than one variable is needed. thanks

Answer (score 6):

In the case you have mentioned you are allowed to do both, there is no reason not to appart from personal preference.

However the current python standard dictates that you should actually do:

```
print("my name is {}".format(playername))
```

Or similar due to the error prone nature of both previous methods. Chances to miss spaces, define the type wrong, etc.

Here is the [relevant PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) which contains some good rational and examples.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the two ways are essentially the same.  I'd do it the second way too :-)  But fancier formatting constructs are definitely useful in fancier contexts - do it whichever way is easier to read.  In recent Pythons, there's also:

```
print "my name is {}".format(playername)
```

That way is more flexible and less error-prone than "%" formatting.  All in good time ;-)

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.5 I'm guessing that is from python 3.? i am using the guide from Learn Python The hard way. i tried finding a guide for 3 but skimming over them i did not like the teaching method in the few i found and it seems like most are still using the 2 standards.

Comment: format is valid in python 2 and 3. Converting the tutorials format strings might be good practice if you want to spend the effort.

Comment: [Here's a link to the 2.7.5 docs for string formats](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).  You're right that there's still a lot more material introducing Python 2 than for Python 3!  That will change in time, but for now I'd stick to Python 2 too :-)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason in this specific case is that `"my name is %s" % playername` gives you a string that you can then manipulate, return, or otherwise process. You can replace `print` with `return` and have it work unchanged.

It's not a big difference at all, but it's *a* reason why you might want to build output that way.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that it's actually more efficient to use %s substitution, but I don't know if that's true.

One reason to get into that habit is that if playername changes to be an object of some class, the first line will still work (assuming the class has implemented `__str__()`) while the second will not give you what you expect.

Comment: `print` will use `__str__()`

Comment: OK so yes right now either works but when i get deeper in it will get problematic so best to start the good habits now. lol i was just wanting to make sure this was not just the personal style of the specific programmer who wrote the tutorial i am using. thanks vey much

Comment: Graeme, Python implicitly applies str() to all the items on a `print` statement.  There's really no significant difference here.

Comment: OK, my mistake. I was sure I'd seen cases where printing an object (rather than '%s' % object) led to something like '<__main__.myclass instance at 0x00001234>' being displayed, but perhaps I'm thinking of something else.